# Android keeping activity from being killed via service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I've searched a lot about keeping activity and I know it's not recommended to keep it alive. However I want it running as long as possible giving it highest priority.

In my app there is remote service with music player and activity with whole data, variables, etc.
Activity is bound to service and is responsible for keeping url's, data, recivers for incoming telephony connections.
Remote service is in foreground mode and started sticky.

It works fine in background, even 30 minutes time is no problem.

My biggest issue is when camera app was launched or telephone call takes long time then activity in background is being killed.

I was wondering if there is any possibility (eg. fake local service in foreground, or let killing activity but not activity process) that would prevent activity from dying?

Comment: That is not a good idea. If the user is not interacting with your application, it's process should be killed if resources are needed. Is the problem that your remote service needs data that the activity has? What is running in the activity that could not be moved into the remote service?

Comment: Login class which is very big, whole database and hashMaps with hundreds of enteries each. There are async tasks and downloaded files info. Services are to slow to retrive needed data.

Comment: The solution is simple. Make few bindings to few services. Even message app is getting killed faster.